# How can I fix the Expected a constant as index error?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying to do some projects on Verilog, and I have a problem with constant index errors.

```
integer k=32;
reg[k-1:0] inputs;
```

In this code, the Verilog compiler gives me this message:

> Expected a constant as index error in Verilog

I must use integer `k` in this project. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`integer` is a **variable** type.  As the error message states, you need a **constant** type, such as `parameter`:

```
parameter k=32;
reg[k-1:0] inputs;
```